# Is casting to IList and then calling ToList() when null better than plain ToList()?

Tags: c#, .net, list, resharper, ienumerable

When I have a `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` from which I don't know wheter its a list or not (in terms of `List<T>`), and I have to enumerate that `IEnumerable` to make sure that I dont enumerate that enumerable twice (such as looping over it twice, or something like that).

Resharper warns me about possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable - which is good, sometimes you forget it - and allows you to chose quickfixes:

- Enumerate to array
- Enumerate to list

When I chose Enumerate to list, resharper introduces a local variable, and assigns the IEnumerable the following way (example):

```
  var enumeratedItems = items as IList<SomeClass> ?? items.ToList();
```

Now my question is:

Why doesn't it simply do `items.ToList();`?

What's the advantage of trying to cast to `IList<SomeClass>` first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the `IEnumerable` is already a list, in this case calling `ToList()` will just create a new List from an exsiting one, so before doing it resharper suggest to try to cast it first to check if it is an `IList` or not and only in case it doesn't we will perform the `ToList()` operation that has some cost.

Comment: Oh I see, makes lots of sense! Thank you :)